# Can you do row locking in Access?

Tags: sql, ms-access, jet, rowlocking

Can you do row locking in Access/JET?

For example, can you do the following in JET SQL:

```
UPDATE Test WITH (ROWLOCK) 
SET UpdateDate = myDate 
WHERE PrimaryKey = myKey
```

Comment: Dont forget to mark this question as anwsered if it worked.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I'm aware you can only achieve this via the options and not in SQL
[image: Options->Advanced]

Answer (score 1):

From [this article](http://www.utteraccess.com/forum/Record-Lock-Access-2003-t706738.html):

Open Access. Then click on Tools-->Options and select the "Advanced" tab.

There you'll find three options for setting Default Record Locks. You'll also find a check box labelled "Open databases using Record-Level Locking". Use "Help" to learn about what each of these options do for you and select the choices that you prefer for your databases.

Comment: @CraigJ  Dont forget to mark this question as anwsered if it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Access doesn't have query hints that I'm aware of.

It should be configurable at the database level.  In Access 2003, for example, you can go to  `Tools > Options`, go to the `Advanced` tab, and you'll find the `Default record locking` option, which gives you the following choices:

- No locks
- All records
- Edited record

In addition, there is a `Open databases using record-level locking` checkbox below that.